# Why is my record update giving a null pointer exception?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert-update

[image]

I am creating notepad application and want to update my notes but I am unable to record in sqlite database. Please check my update query
I am sharing error details.

```
public class MainUpdateActivity extends Activity  { 

SQLiteDatabase mydb1;
EditText titleedit,notetextedit;
Button update;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        titleedit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
        notetextedit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.notetext);
        update=(Button) findViewById(R.id.update);

        Intent myintent = getIntent();

        String product7 = myintent.getStringExtra("product1");
        String product8 = myintent.getStringExtra("product");

        titleedit.setText(product7);
          notetextedit.setText(product8);

update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
mydb1.execSQL("UPDATE notes SET (title,notetext) values(?,?);",new String[]{titleedit.getText().toString(),notetextedit.getText().toString()});

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "note Updated", 3000).show();



            Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(MainUpdateActivity.this,menu.class);

            startActivity(myIntent1);

            finish();

            }

            });
```

Comment: what is your MainUpdateActivity line 63?

Comment: mydb1.execSQL("UPDATE notes SET (title,notetext) values(?,?);",new String[]{titleedit.getText().toString(),notetextedit.getText().toString()});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like in

```
mydb1.execSQL("UPDATE notes SET (title,notetext) values(?,?);",new String[]{titleedit.getText().toString(),notetextedit.getText().toString()});
```

`mydb1` is null,you didn't new and init `mydb1`.

Comment: Note: an **explicit** `.toString()` conversion is not really needed, here, since the inclusion in the string array will automatically perform the **implicit** conversions.

Comment: yes,`toString` can be removed.

Comment: no its not null it has two record.

Comment: @ramanrayat,I mean you don't init value for `mydb1`.For exmaple,you should use `SqlLiteOpenHelper.getWriteableDatabase()` to init it.

Comment: still i didn't get you please correct my code if you can..

Comment: Please refer [sqlite doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db),you should create your own  `SqlLiteOpenHelper`,and create databse then init `mydb1`.

Comment: i can't do this at this stage because it already a very large code.do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: Thanks i correct it by my way ;)

public class MainUpdateActivity extends Main1Activity (it include insert query where my database is initializing )

Answer (score 4):

you have declared `SQLiteDatabase mydb1` but not initialized it. Error is in this line.

```
mydb1.execSQL("UPDATE notes SET (title,notetext) values(?,?);",new String[]{titleedit.getText().toString(),notetextedit.getText().toString()});
```

You need to initialize `mydb1`.

Comment: thanks i correct it :)